# How do I check if an element of an array of classes is empty? [c++]

Tags: c++, arrays, class, hashmap, hashtable

For my latest assignment, I need to create a hash table that houses stocks, which are encapsulated in a class. To avoid collisions, I need to use linear probing. The problem I've run into, however; is that I can't test whether or not an element of the array (which is the hash table) is empty.

Here's some code aggregated from several files, but this is just to give you an idea of what's going on.

```
class Stock{

friend class HashMap

}

class HashMap{

bool get() //this function is used for putting new stocks into the table
private:
  struct Slot {
    Stock  slotStock;
  }
Slot *slots;
}
```

Within the get() function

```
while(slots[index] != NULL)
```

This gives an error: no operator "!=" matches these operands HashMap::Slot != int

What alternative way would there be for me to check whether or not a slot is empty?

The array is allocated dynamically.

EDIT: When I initialize the array, does it use the default constructor to create an object for each element of the array, or does it leave the elements empty?

Comment: C++ objects have no notion of empty like Java references do.

Comment: You could have a flag for each slot whether it is valid or not. Even if not valid, a slot object would still exist, although maybe not in a useful state.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of objects of type `X`, none of the slots are "empty". They all contain an object of type `X`. To represent an empty object, it needs to be a possible state of the type which is stored in the array.  You could, for example, have `boost::optional<Slot>`, or `std::unique_ptr<Slot>`. Otherwise, you can encode the state directly into your `Slot` class (with a bool member, for example).

Comment: Okay, thanks. So when the array is dynamically allocated, it creates an object for each element using the default constructor?

Comment: Or perhaps use a `std::pair<Slot, bool>` if you don't want to add the flag directly to the slot object.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is store an array of **Stock** pointers, whereas you are currently storing an array of **Slot** objects.  To make things even easier on yourself, you can use a vector to store the pointers.

Your backing data structure would look like this:

```
std::vector< Stock* > vecStocks;
```

Each item in the vector is a "slot", and you do not need your Slot class unless you intend to store some metadata about the stock.

To check whether or not you have a stock in any slot of the vector, you compare the vector item to NULL like this:

```
if (vecStocks[index] == NULL)
```

This approach has the positive side effect of not needing to allocate X number of Stock objects up front, where X is the size of your hashmap (potentially a very large number, depending on how often you like to collide).

Comment: @NeilKirk The vector is simply holding pointers to objects on the heap.  The writer of the hashmap typically will make the public interface accept object pointers for map insertion, which puts the onus on the caller to manage the objects on the heap (create them, and at some point destroy them).

Comment: @NeilKirk Maybe you mean shared_ptr.  unique_ptr will not work for this since it is non-copyable and doesn't make sense (nor will it compile).  Storing as a vector of shared_ptrs is possible, but it requires that the user of the hashmap provide the map values as shared_ptrs.  It also requires that you compile with C++11 or use boost::shared_ptr instead.  If your program is already on the shared_ptr train, then it is a good choice.

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Stock>>` will compile, it's a common design pattern. Perhaps you are thinking of `auto_ptr`

Comment: @NeilKirk Looked more into this and you are right, although it requires _move_ semantics provided in C++11.  Public interface has to take in the data using unique_ptrs, of course.  Also, it seems that a get() operation could only return by value, since you cannot return a copy of the unique_ptr and you certainly don't want to _move_ it out.  Nonetheless, by this point I think we have diverged a bit from the OPs question.